# Touch device HTML element :hover state

Tags: javascript, css, hover, touch, ipod-touch

There is a HTML button, with 3 backgrounds - each for normal, hover and clicked states. Of course, it works fine with non touch device. If the button is clicked on touch device, the :hover state is also triggered and stays until another element is touched.

Is it possible to programmatically remove :hover state from element after it was clicked or prevent it from activating on touch devices?

Sorry, but suggestions to a detect mouseover and mouseout events and add artificial classes are not accepted.

One possible solution is to add "no-touch" class to html element in advance and remove it if only touch device is detected. In that case, CSS selector "html.no-touch button:hover" will not match for touch device.

Do you know more elegant solutions you may suggest?

Comment: Are we to assume that you can't just get by without `:hover`?  As in, for some reason `:hover` just not being used is an issue, since it seems to me the other two states should work just fine.

Comment: Ignoring :hover support, will make a web application a little bit less interactive for users without touch devices. In case no reliable solution will be found, this requirement will be removed, because :hover on touch device creates even more visual problems.

Comment: Interesting.  I would have expected mobile browsers to just ignore `:hover` since you can't actually hover over an element anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to overwrite the `:hover` state in an additional style-sheet for handheld devices like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="handheld.css" media="handheld">
```

and in `handheld.css` put something like:

```
#some_selector:hover {
    background: none;    /* if you are setting a background in the main css file for example */
}
```

However, I´m not sure if `handheld` and touch screen are completely the same, there might be devices that have a touch screen and are not qualified as a handheld.

**Edit:** It seems you cannot detect touch screen devices 100% reliably, also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607248/optimize-website-for-touch-devices).

Comment: To make things even complicated, media="handheld" is ignored by Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this issue can be resolved by overwriting the :hover state for a given element in media query - see this question:

[CSS hover not being ignored on touch screen devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936464/css-hover-not-being-ignored-on-touch-screen-devices)