# CSS hover not being ignored on touch-screen devices

Tags: jquery, html, button, hover, touch

I've appended a div with a html button:

```
$('.nav').append('<button class="restart">Restart</button>');
```

The button has css properties for hover. My problem is that when tapping the button on a touch-screen device, the button retains its hover state until another element is tapped.

Is there any way that the hover property can be ignored when browsing with a touch-screen device?

Comment: Do you have the attribute `type="button"`? If not, the button becomes a submit button by default.

Comment: @Neal Yes it is, look at the spec. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html "The missing value default is the Submit Button state."

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle yes **what** is?

Comment: I am just trying to tell this person that they are going to have other fish to fry if they don't want this button to submit to the current page.

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle why would it submit if there is no form?!

Comment: When was submitting a form ever mentioned in any way?

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle See Matt's comment above ^^^

Comment: To be fair, the element with class 'restart' doesn't necessarily need to be a button, an anchor would do the same job but I'm getting the same problem with an anchor too.

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle You are wrong. A button submits its form. If a button is not in a form, it can not submit it since there is no "default form" that could be submitted. So it will not do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an ideal solution, but thanks @dualed for the headstart!

```
@media screen and (min-device-width:768px) and (max-device-width:1024px) /*catch touch screen devices */
{
    button.restart:hover
    {
        /* replicate 'up' state of element */
    }
}
```

Comment: What about smaller laptops (e.g. MS surface) where a mouse is plugged in in portrait? This is a sub-ideal method.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this exact problem recently, iOS seems to consider the hover psuedo as an additional click, so links will needs clicking twice etc.

If you use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) you can apply your :hover psuedos through the .no-touch class which is applied to the html tag.

so:

```
html a { color:#222; }

html.no-touch a:hover { color:#111; }
```

Comment: Here is the iOS documentation about how events are triggered on clickable elements: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW7

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the media type in your CSS rules.

```
@media handheld {
  button.restart:hover {
    /* undo hover styling */
  }
}
```

However, note that hand held devices do not necessarily have a touch screen.

(Btw. this is CSS not jQuery)

Comment: Handheld doesn't work too well, but by specifying device-width in the query, I've got a solution.

Comment: @rhastings that might work, but may have other side-effects. You may have to specify exact device sizes. Sadly the mozilla `-moz-touch-enabled` has no equivalent implementations on webkit. Also, I assume we are talking about the i-range of mobile products, look here http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safaricssref/Articles/OtherStandardCSS3Features.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007601-SW3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's not what you want, but you can specify different css stylesheets depending on the media :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection,tv" href="main.css" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="handheld" href="smallscreen.css" type="text/css">
```

in above example, main.css will be used for computer screens but for a handeld device, it will be smallscreen.css

Comment: correct, though almost all touch devices currently report themselves as 'screen', not handheld.

Answer (score -2):

One nice and easy way is using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

When Modernizr runs, it will add an entry in the class attribute of the HTML
 tag for every feature it detects, prefixing the feature with no- if the browser
doesn’t support it.

Now add following lines to your css stylesheet

```
.touch *:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

And freely use :hover as many times as you like. When your site is viewed in touch screens hover effect of all elements will be disabled.

Comment: Also, * in css is *incredibly* inefficient. However, this technique should work, from the technical standpoint.