# Android needs two button clicks to run Jquery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax

I have a Jquery function that runs when the button is clicked. This works perfect on my computer but when tested on my android phone it needed two button clicks to work?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#thisid').hide();

        $("#button-create").click(function(event){
           var name = $("#create").val();
            var name2 = $("#create2").val();
           $("#stage").load('result.php', {name:name, name2:name2} );

        });
     });
  </script>
```

Button:

```
<button id="button-create" class="btn1">Create</button>
```

CSS:

```
 .btn1{
background-color:#ff7743;
border:0;
height:30px;
width:60px;
font-size: 18px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}

 .btn1:hover{

 color: inherit;
 background-color:#ff7743;

 }
.btn1:focus {outline:0;}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885255/how-to-remove-ignore-hover-css-style-on-touch-devices) out

Comment: Cant get it to work! @Jack

Answer (score 1):

There is no problems with your script. Look into your CSS file on "#button-create" style and disable all ":hoover" styles in your mobile version.

Comment: Your button not change color or shadow effects on mouse hover and mouse leave?

Comment: There is the standard hover but that shouldent by a problem?

Comment: @Anton that is exactly the problem. Touch devices take the first touch as a hover, the second as the click.

Comment: It doesent work, Please take a look on the updated question. @Jack

Comment: remove this style: .btn1:hover{

 color: inherit;
 background-color:#ff7743;

 }

Comment: That's not the problem. There is an standard hover effect on the button. I tried to remove that. How should I do instead?