# CSS pseudo class for touch

Tags: css, touchdevelop

I try to create a [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) **CSS only theme**, that hides the attributes section and only shows it on mouse-click or touch.

I added the [Pseudo Class](http://www.css4you.de/pseudoklproperty.html) `:active` which works fine on desktops, but on Android Chrome, it only activates for a fraction of a second and then it looses this attribute again (because it starts a selection for copy and paste then instead)

```
.details > .attributes {
        height:20px;
        overflow:hidden;
        display: block;
        cursor:pointer;
}
.details > .attributes:hover {
        background-color:#ddd;
}
.details > .attributes:active, .details > .attributes:focus {
        height:auto;
}
```

(here I added the `:focus` attribute as well, but that didn't change anything)

How can I bypass this without editing the html-code and without javascript?

Comment: is there anything in the html can can be used when on a mobile device? like a `.mobile` class on the `body` when viewed on a touch device?

Comment: I think redmine doesn't have this. the problem is, `.attributes` is just a div with that class, and divs can't have a focus

Comment: you can disable focus/hover etc on touch devices which would fix your problem as well as boost perf on those devices, but you'd need something in the css to differentiate from desktop. [here is a js method, although I know you want a pure css solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885255/how-to-remove-ignore-hover-css-style-on-touch-devices) not sure how you'd do it if you can't differentiate

Comment: You can use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect if the device has touch events, and if it does have, you can additional markup.

Comment: I want to keep it all in the one redmine css theme file

Answer (score 0):

As a **workaround**, I added now a transition and keep it open on `:hover`:

```
.details > .attributes {
        height:20px;
        overflow:hidden;
        display: block;
        cursor:pointer;
}
.details > .attributes:hover {
        background-color:#ddd;
}
.details > .attributes:active, .details > .attributes:hover {
        height:120px;
        overflow:auto;
        transition: height 1.1s ease-in;
}
```

it is only a workaround, because this doesn't work with `height:auto` because there is no transition possible from `height:20px` to `height:auto`. I defined 120px which seems to be enough in most cases, but if it doesn't fit, the overflow: auto will show a sclŕollbar at the side of the div (which is acceptable)