# Disable :hover CSS on Mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have the following CSS defined on some `img` elements on my page.

```
.my-image {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.my-image:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5);
    transform:scale(1.5);
}
```

For some reason, the hover class is activating on an iPhone anytime I scroll past it (that is, move my finger along the images to scroll past them). Is there any way I can disable the hover CSS for mobile only?

Comment: you can add media tag, but thats applies to screen sizes

Comment: Yeah, that might be what I want though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/ignore :hover css style on touch devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885255/how-to-remove-ignore-hover-css-style-on-touch-devices)

Answer (score 9):

```
@media handheld {
.my-image:hover {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}
}
```

**UPDATE**: On September 5, 2017, the Media Queries 4 specification was adopted, in which the `handheld` tag was deprecated. it is recommended to use the `hover` media query - for devices where you can hover over and item without clicking and `not hover` where you cannot.

```
@media (not hover) {
.my-image:hover {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}
}
```

You can also use the media query `pointer:(coarse|fine|one)`. `coarse` — for finger-controlled touchscreens, `fine` for mouse or stylus, and `none` for others.

```
@media (pointer:coarse) {
.my-image:hover {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -moz-transform: none;
    -ms-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}
}
```

Comment: Wow, is handheld a real media tag?

Comment: List of media types: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/317/media-queries/7625/mediatype#t=201607281352142207415

Comment: Is handheld preferred over aiming for a screen size?

Comment: i think this not associated with screen size

Comment: The "handheld" media type is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: @enriquejr99 At the time of the answer it was valid. )

Answer (score 0):

add media query like

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
.my-image:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5);
    transform:scale(1.5);
}
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I ended up with something similar...Curious, will this handle iPad as well?

Comment: ipad screen size 1024x768 for landscape & 768x1024 for portrait