# Problem with CSS media query to detect if Samsung device supports hover

Tags: android, css, samsung-mobile

I'd like to use pure css to provide different behavior for devices that do not support hover. This is easily achievable on iOS and Google devices with:

```css
@media (hover: none) {
}
```

However, Android devices do not seem to support this in the way that I expect. Here is a simple test case:
https://codepen.io/kylegordy/pen/abOLbXV

I would expect all green on a device that supports hover (like a desktop) and all red on a device that does not. But Samsung phones fail with both media queries for hover.

It seems that we can work around this by testing `pointer: coarse`, but that isn't what we are actually trying to test, so I'm reluctant to use this as a workaround. Is there some other solution I should be considering?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove/ignore :hover css style on touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885255/how-to-remove-ignore-hover-css-style-on-touch-devices)

Comment: Seems like a pretty clear bug in Samsung Android implementation. I reported this issue to both Google and Samsung but the UIs that I used didn't provide any publicly available bug reports for others to follow.

Answer (score 2):

For now I am using the same solution as you mentioned:

```
@media (hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {
  ...
}
```

`(pointer: fine)`: Only a mouse pointer (or similar) will trigger this media query. This query is helpful since a Samsung device supports both - touch and mouse input.

Probably it's best to always use the `(pointer: fine)` unless you want touch events to trigger hover effects on those devices.