# Touch event triggers `:hover` in Svelte

Tags: css, web, svelte, sveltekit

[image]

Hello, guys! I need some on `:hover` CSS changes to animate the component in `Svelte` project. I only need this behavior on devices with the pointer, I don't need touch events to trigger them. And I thought that's what `:hover` exists for. But unfortunately touch events can imitate hover. I was looking for an answer and found this one:

```js
@media(hover: hover){
.your-class:hover{color: red}
}
```

This `@media` tag actually tracking if the device has a pointer or not. If not, hover event won't be executed. My question is: is it the right and overall the best way to achieve what's expected?
Here's minimal [demonstration repo](https://svelte.dev/repl/34f24fc6f2f842bc9fc4e283e7eabb35?version=3.59.1).
If you're in Chrome - RMB click -> Inspect -> Toggle device toolbar (in a top left corner of dev tools) -> select Nest Hub Max. Now cursor becomes a "finger" and you could push on the div and it will animate. If you're in another browser - do something similar with it's dev tools. Just be sure to select the touchscreen device with the screen big enough to display all the content of the repo.

Comment: I’m not too sure what the question is here as you seem to have found an answer by using that media query. Could you explain what the problem is a bit more?

Comment: @AHaworth "My question is: is it the right and overall the best way to achieve what's expected?"

Comment: I think an answer to that would result in opinions rather than hard facts which SO does not allow so voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to assume relatively new browsers, then this will definitely be the easiest solution. [The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885255/how-to-remove-ignore-hover-css-style-on-touch-devices) gives an overview of 3 different options: Using CSS `@media (hover: hover)`, Using Javascript to remove `:hover` styles, and a combination of JS and CSS which is more robust (and more abstract).

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, and what your target audience is, there are multiple solutions to achieve the same thing. So even though there is no "right" answer, your way of doing things makes sense.