# How to determine if the client is a touch device

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, tablet

is there any nice and clean method or trick to find out if the user is on a touch-device or not?

I know there is stuff like
`var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;`

but I simply wonder if there is a trick to generally determine if the user is on Touch device?
Because there are a lot more touch devices and tablets out there then just iPads.

thank you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the following JS function:

```
function isTouchDevice() {
   var el = document.createElement('div');
   el.setAttribute('ongesturestart', 'return;'); // or try "ontouchstart"
   return typeof el.ongesturestart === "function";
}
```

Source: [Detecting touch-based browsing](http://alastairc.ac/2010/03/detecting-touch-based-browsing/).

Please note the above code only tests if the browser has support for touch, not the device.

Related links:

- [How to detect a mobile device using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/how-to-detect-a-mobile-device-using-jquery)
- [How to optimize website for touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607248/optimize-website-for-touch-devices)
- [How to detect a mobile device using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery)
- [What's the best way to detect a 'touch screen' device using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript)
- [Mozilla.org Detecting touch: it’s the ‘why’, not the ‘how’](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/04/detecting-touch-its-the-why-not-the-how/)

There may be detection in [jquery for mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and [jtouch](http://jqtouch.com/)

Comment: Works for iPhone, but what about Androids, BlackBerries, Symbians, WebOS...?

Comment: Not a useful comment. Does not work how? Did you `alert(typeof el.ongesturestart)` or what did you try? What device? What OS? Downvoting without a constructive message is not helping anyone. Also this is a 2 year old post. The world has moved since

Comment: Returns false on iPhone with iOS 7.0.6 using Safari.

Comment: Do any of these work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript

Comment: Or this https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/04/detecting-touch-its-the-why-not-the-how/

Answer (score 14):

Include [modernizer](http://www.modernizr.com/), which is a tiny feature detection library. Then you can use something like below.

```
if (Modernizr.touch){
   // bind to touchstart, touchmove, etc and watch `event.streamId`
} else {
   // bind to normal click, mousemove, etc
}
```

Comment: Feature detection > UA Checking.

Answer (score 14):

```
if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)
{
  alert("It's a touch screen device.");
}
else
{
 alert("Others devices");
}
```

most simple code i found after browsing a lot here and there

Comment: I wouldn't trust this as it shows true on my mac which is not a touch device. This simply asks if the browser supports it .. i think

Answer (score 4):

Using `document.createEvent("TouchEvent")` will not work on desktop-devices. So you can use it inside an if statement.

Note that this method could produce errors on non-touch devices. I would prefer checking for `ontouchstart`  in `document.documentElement`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [post](http://www.sitepoint.com/adapting-an-interface-for-touch-devices/), it gives a really nice code snippet for what to do when touch devices are detected or what to do if touchstart event is called:

```
$(function(){
  if(window.Touch) {
    touch_detect.auto_detected();
  } else {
    document.ontouchstart = touch_detect.surface;
  }
}); // End loaded jQuery
var touch_detect = {
  auto_detected: function(event){
    /* add everything you want to do onLoad here (eg. activating hover controls) */
    alert('this was auto detected');
    activateTouchArea();
  },
  surface: function(event){
    /* add everything you want to do ontouchstart here (eg. drag & drop) - you can fire this in both places */
    alert('this was detected by touching');
    activateTouchArea();
  }
}; // touch_detect
function activateTouchArea(){
  /* make sure our screen doesn't scroll when we move the "touchable area" */
  var element = document.getElementById('element_id');
  element.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStart, false);
}
function touchStart(event) {
  /* modularize preventing the default behavior so we can use it again */
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), it is very easy to use `Modernizr.touch` as mentioned earlier.

However, I prefer using a combination of `Modernizr.touch` and user agent testing, just to be safe.

```
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

var isTouchDevice = Modernizr.touch || 
(deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/) ||
deviceAgent.match(/(android)/)  || 
deviceAgent.match(/(iemobile)/) || 
deviceAgent.match(/iphone/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/ipad/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/ipod/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/blackberry/i) || 
deviceAgent.match(/bada/i));

if (isTouchDevice) {
        //Do something touchy
    } else {
        //Can't touch this
    }
```

If you don't use Modernizr, you can simply replace the `Modernizr.touch` function above with `('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement)`

Also note that testing the user agent `iemobile` will give you broader range of detected Microsoft mobile devices than `Windows Phone`.

[Also see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262584/how-to-determine-if-the-client-is-a-touch-device)

Comment: Your user agent detection logic is broken: you are assuming every mobile device has a touchscreen. Some Blackberry models (OS <= 7) for instance don't have one. Even in iPhone someone might create an eye-movement controlled browser that does not feature touch events. and finally you could have used the `/Mobile/i` regex instead of that long OR.

Comment: what about touch screens or desktops, this does not detect that.