# How to detect Android tablet browser?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, browser-detection

I have used following code to detect mobile/tablet browser.

```
function isMobile() {
        var index = navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mobile");
        return (index > -1);
    }
```

It is working well for desktop browsers and also iOS devices (iPhone/iPad) but it can not detect some of Android tablet or mobile devices.

I have used following snippet also but that also not worked.

```
var Environment = {
    //mobile or desktop compatible event name, to be used with '.on' function
    TOUCH_DOWN_EVENT_NAME: 'mousedown touchstart',
    TOUCH_UP_EVENT_NAME: 'mouseup touchend',
    TOUCH_MOVE_EVENT_NAME: 'mousemove touchmove',
    TOUCH_DOUBLE_TAB_EVENT_NAME: 'dblclick dbltap',

    isAndroid: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    isBlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    isIOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    isOpera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    isWindows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    isMobile: function() {
        return (Environment.isAndroid() || Environment.isBlackBerry() || Environment.isIOS() || Environment.isOpera() || Environment.isWindows());
    }
};
```

Can any body please tell me is there any mistake or I need to use any other method.

Answer (score 0):

visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262584/how-to-determine-if-the-client-is-a-touch-device)

```
function isTouchDevice() {
   var el = document.createElement('div');
   el.setAttribute('ongesturestart', 'return;');
   return typeof el.ongesturestart === "function";
}
```

Comment: you can visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet