# how to identify touch enabled mobile devices

Tags: php, touch, mobile-website, user-agent

I want to have a mobile website **view** specifically for touch enabled mobile phones.
I already have a mobile website for simple mobiles having user agent 'mobile' and for desktops or big screens as 'desk'. 
I dont want a version touch.*.com rather i want a technique which redirects users automatically to the the optimized website for the device like many mobile sites do for eg facebook.

How should i go for it?

Comment: No other answer have been posted and I clearly put you on a solution path providing a link to an implemented php service that allow you to detect which device is making a request from the php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a bit of research and this is what I found
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WURFL

The PHP implementation 
http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/nphp/

Front End

Same question from an other post "valid answer"
[What's the best way to detect a 'touch screen' device using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript)

The info can be found on the following "require reading"

[Optimize website for touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607248/optimize-website-for-touch-devices)

And a bit more details on how moderniz detect it

http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html

Hope that help

Comment: I want to identify it in PHP!

Comment: Maybe you should have define this before? Please improve your question and give the langugae context you want the issue to be resolved in.